# What is the name for component of menu board in front of home slider app

Tags: gui-design, design, menu, app, component

What's the name / the called for the component of menus board in front of home slider app. Usually it's contains of several feature services/action of the app. I mark with red frame on this image attached.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would call this a "Tab". It's similar. The first navigation in this application is the "Bottom navigation". Here, we are on the home page. Subcategories and first functionalities of home page can be on a tab at the top of the page.

Like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As others have already mentioned, there's no name for that that I remember.
I've called them **Inline navigation bar** or **Quick navigation bar**

Answer (score 0):

There is no name to it currently. When some big company assigns it a name in their design language, it becomes part of the common jargon in the design industry.

That said, this section is used to surface the most used actions by users of an app. These almost always end up being the primary purposes of the app. You can see examples of these in mega apps which provide a lot of services.

Ex: GoJek, Paytm, Aliexpress, Grab